# How is a subview of an NSView dynamically positioned?

Tags: cocoa, swift

I am attempting to change the coordinates of an NSButton that is contained within a parent NSView and something is clearly not working, because the button position does not change. Both elements are defined in a nib file and the parent view has animation applied to it using CoreAnimation.

I have tried the following.

`button.frame.origin.x = 500`

and...

```
var frame:CGRect = button.frame
frame.origin.x = 500
button.frame = frame
```

Even with the animations disabled, I can not seem to dynamically position the subview. Is there some feature that prevents children views from being positioned programmatically?

Please note that I am using Swift with XCode 6.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using AutoLayout constraints, given you're using the latest tools.

If so, setting a subview's frame directly won't work the way you're expecting (if it does anything at all, it'll cause strange drawing glitches / flashing when mixed with animation). You have to create outlets for your layout constraints and modify them.

If you're not using AutoLayout, I suggest having a look at your `button` outlet to make sure it's actually connected (ie, you're not talking to `nil`). Even if the outlet is connected, make sure it's not `nil` at runtime - you may be trying to talk to the button before the nib is loaded and the outlet / action connections are restored.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. How would I go about finding out whether or not AutoLayout is being used? I don't see options for AutoLayout in Interface Builder.

Comment: It's the default optuon. But if you added no constraints to the button, AutoLayout should leave its frame alone.